# Passing StringBuilder to DLL function expecting char pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dllimport

I'm trying to interact with a DLL library created in Delphi.  In C++, I made this call perfectly fine:

```
for(int y = 1; y <= 12; y++)
{
    char * chanName = (char *) malloc(21); 
    memset(chanName,0,21);
    channelName(y,20,chanName);
    ...
}
```

Where `channelName` is type defined as `typedef int (CALLBACK* ChannelName)(int,int,char*);`

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in C#.  I've searched and found that `StringBuilder` is commonly used as a char pointer for DLL functions.  Here is how I declared my function:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
public static extern int ChannelName(int x, int y, StringBuilder z);
```

And here is how I'm trying to call it:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(100);
    DLLInterface.ChannelName(x+1, b.Length, b);
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```

This is just making the console print out jibberish, for example:

```
☺ §
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
☺ î☺8f9
```

I remember running into a similar problem in C++ which is why I `memset` the memory that I `malloc` to 0.  I tried to find an equivalent in C#, but maybe it's an issue with the `StringBuilder` instead?  In case my question isn't very clear, I just want to be able to pass a string into my function, have the function fill it up, and then print it out.  Strings are immutable in C# and no good pointer options exist which is why I'm trying `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the string as ref string z ?

Comment: You should just be trying with `string`

Comment: I tried using the `ref string z` and then passing in the string "" as a ref and it printed out blank lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET, strings (and StringBuilders) are 16-bit Unicode characters. My guess is that you native function deals in 8-bit ASCII characters. You need to tell the Marshaller how to convert the characters when marshalling them. Change your DllImport attribute like so:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int ChannelName(int x, int y, [Out] StringBuilder z);
```

**Updated**

Also you should specify the [Out] attribute on the StringBuilder so that the Marshaller only marshals on the way out as you are passing nothing on the way in.

**Updated Again**

The [In,Out] attribute is redundant (that's the default), however putting it there makes it explicit that you know you desire both In and Out copying.

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
private static extern int ChannelName(int x, int y, [In,Out] byte[] z);
public static int ChannelName(int x, int y, out string result)
{
    byte[] z = new byte[100];
    int ret = ChannelName(x, y, z);
    result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(z);
    return ret;
}
```

**Updated Again**

It looks like the (poorly named) 'y' parameter is the length of the char * buffer passed in and my guess is that it returns the number of characters written into the buffer. If that is the case, I would wrap this invocation in a more natural C# way:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
private static extern int ChannelName(int x, int y, [In, Out] byte[] z);

public static string ChannelName(int x)
{
    byte[] z = new byte[100];
    int length = ChannelName(x, z.Length, z);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(z, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: This didn't do much except change the jibberish to different jibberish. I tried tens of combinations with different CharSet's, swapping [out] for ref, etc, but nothing worked. For some reason I think it has to do with a memory issue.  I remember getting jibberish when I wrote the solution in C++ until I used ZeroMemory() on the memory chunk I allocated.  Is there a related method in C#?

Comment: @Atlos So in your case, you **want** to marshal both In and Out. Did you try removing the Out attribute (ref is not correct). It may be the case that the marshaller is "smart" about marshalling StringBuilder's (not copying all the zero bytes), try a byte[] instead and use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` on the resulting array to get the String back.

Comment: Thank you!  The very last update solved my problem with one modification.  ChannelName actually returns an error code so I just replaced `length` with a fixed number for now.  Sorry for my horrible variable naming, I do that when I write a lot of things in a hurry and then refactor after I have the working solution.  Anyways, I believe what you did makes sense.

Comment: @Atlos You're welcome. Use the overload of Encoding.ASCII.GetString which only takes the array. If you pass an offset and length to it, the returned string will have that exact length, with a bunch of zeros on the end (embedded zeros are legal in C#). The array-only overload will truncate the string when it finds the first zero.

Comment: @Atlos Actually, it's not true. Encoding.GetString returns a string of the array's length if you don't specify offset,length. You can use `.TrimEnd((char)0)` to truncate the trailing zeros.

Comment: I did `DllInterface.ChannelName(x + 1).Trim()` and it works fine.  Thanks again.