# Receive char ** from a C++ DLL into C# string[]

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, string, dll

Despite all the questions, I can't find a suitable answer for doing this.

My goal is to **fill a `string[]` with the use of a DLL that returns a `char**`**.

**DLL Declaration** :

```
extern "C" SHTSDK_EXPORT int GetPeerList(SHTSDK::Camera *camera, int* id, int id_size, char** name, int name_size, int* statut, int statut_size);
```

**My import** :

```
[DllImport(libName)]
static public extern int GetPeerList(IntPtr camera, IntPtr id, int id_size, IntPtr name, int name_size, IntPtr statut, int statut_size);
```

**My use in C# code** :

```
StringBuilder[] name = new StringBuilder[nbPeer];
for (int i = 0; i < nbPeer; i++)
{
     name[i] = new StringBuilder(256);
}
//Alloc peer name array
GCHandle nameHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(name, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointeurName = nameHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

int notNewConnection = APIServices.GetPeerList(cameraStreaming, pointeurId, 

nbPeer, pointeurName, nbPeer, pointeurStatut, nbPeer);

// Now I'm supposed to read string with name[i] but it crashes
```

What did I miss? I really searched on the other topics, I thought [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733313/how-to-get-char-using-c) could work, but still crashing.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest making a mixed assembly ( visual C++ with a cli support ) and use this as a wrapper on native ( C++ ) functions. It is far more easier than what you've done right now.

Comment: Maybe it could be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508260/passing-stringbuilder-to-dll-function-expecting-char-pointer#11509815

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you developing a tiny **C++/CLI** *bridging* layer. The purpose of this C++/CLI bridge is to take the string array returned by the DLL in the form of `char**` raw pointers, and convert it to a .NET string array, that can be consumed in your C# code as a simple `string[]`.

The C++/CLI version of C# `string[]` (string array) is `array<String^>^`, e.g.:

```
array<String^>^ managedStringArray = gcnew array<String^>(count);
```

You can use the usual syntax with `operator[]` (i.e. `managedStringArray[index]`) to assign each string to the array.

You may write some code like this:

```
// C++/CLI wrapper around your C++ native DLL
ref class YourDllWrapper
{
public:
    // Wrap the call to the function of your native C++ DLL,
    // and return the string array using the .NET managed array type
    array<String^>^ GetPeerList( /* parameters ... */ )
    {
        // C++ code that calls your DLL function, and gets
        // the string array from the DLL.
        // ...

        // Build a .NET string array and fill it with
        // the strings returned from the native DLL 
        array<String^>^ result = gcnew array<String^>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            result[i] = /* i-th string from the DLL */ ;
        }

        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

You may find [this article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7704/Arrays-in-C-CLI) on C++/CLI arrays an interesting reading as well.

---

**P.S.** The strings returned from your native DLL are in the form of `char`-strings. On the other hand, .NET strings are **Unicode UTF-16** strings. So you need to clarify what encoding is used to represent text in your native strings, and convert to UTF-16 for .NET strings.