# Converting from string to char* only copies the first character

Tags: c#, unsafe

I have looked at most of the string to char* conversion SO answers, but it is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
public static void Main() {
    string name = "ELEM";
    unsafe{
          fixed(char* name_ptr = name) {
              Console.WriteLine(name_ptr->ToString());
          }
    }
} 
// Output: E
```

I need to do this since I have to pass a char* to my C++ custom DLL. Why would it only copy the first character only, and how can I properly convert string to a char*?

Comment: use a StringBuilder instance instead... see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508260/passing-stringbuilder-to-dll-function-expecting-char-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the first character only, because name_ptr is nothing but a reference to a single character and when you call `name_ptr->ToString()` you actually call `char.ToString()`.

You should use a `StringBuilder` instead to pass a string to a C/C++ DLL.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508260/passing-stringbuilder-to-dll-function-expecting-char-pointer).